The number of triangles whose vertices are at the vertices of an octagon but none of whose sides happen to come from the sides of the octagon is 16.
Show that the number of triangles whose vertices are at the vertices of an octagon but none of whose sides happen to come from the sides of the octagon is 16.
Ans: From 8 vertices, one point (Say A) is selected in $\binom{8}{1}$ ways.
We have to select two non-consecutive points which are not adjacent to the point A. There exists 4 such points. It can be done in $\binom{8-4}{2}$ ways.
So the reqd. ans:=  $\binom{8}{1} \times \binom{8-4}{2}$
But I am not getting the answer. Please explain in a simple way to get the answer.

Well, you also need the two points "extra" points to be non-adjacent to each other.

Your method appears to be incomplete, as you do not require that the "other two" points, besides $A$, be non-adjacent.
It's easiest, I think to simply enumerate the cases.  Number the vertices cyclically from $1$ to $8$.  Say we start with $1$.  Then the possible pairs that work are $$(3,5)\quad (3,6)\quad (3,7)\quad (4,6)\quad (4,7)\quad (5,7)$$
Hence there are six good triangles containing the vertex $\#1$.  As there are $8$ starting vertices, we get $8\times 6$ triangles but, of course, we count each triangle exactly three times so the desired answer is $$\frac {8\times 6}3=16$$
To handle the "enumeration" systematically, consider the gaps.  Starting with $\#1$ we have the gap $g_1$ between $\#1$ and the next smallest vertex, then $g_2$ to get to the next vertex, then $g_3$ to get back to $\#1$.  Of course $g_i≥1$ for all $i$ and $\sum g_i=5$.  Stars and Bars then tells us that the total count is $$\binom 42=6$$ confirming our explicit count.
It follows that if we asked the same question about an $n-$gon instead of just an $8-$gon the answer would be $$n\times \binom {n-4}2\times \frac 13$$
Sanity Check:  If $n=6$ this gives $2$ and indeed there are exactly two good triangles in this case:  $(1,3,5)$ and $(2,4,6)$.

The error in your method is that you are not accounting for the fact that the other two points must also be non-adjacent to each other. This creates several extra cases.
We will solve this using complementary counting(counting total cases and then subtracting the undesirable ones).
Total ways to select 3 points(make a triangle) is 8C3 or 56. Now undesirable cases can be split into 2 categories:

The triangle uses only one side of the octagon.

There are 8 ways to choose the side, and then 4 ways to choose the point such that it is not adjacent to any of the already chosen points(and hence does not take up another side). Hence this makes 32 undesirable cases.

The triangle uses 2 sides of the octagon. Now we know there are 8 ways to do this, as we can pick any side(which takes up 2 points) and place the third one directly to the right of that side.

The triangle obviously cannot have all 3 sides from the octagon. So we have considered all undesirable cases.
Hence our final answer is 56 - 32 - 8 = 16.

Hope this helped.

